# if watson conversation response message can include rich text and picture

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

does anyone know if conversation response message can include rich text and picture? or the response message can only be text. Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to include images using back-end coding where you override the normal conversation flow and include the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be only text per API:

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/

Answer (score -1):

You can add images by putting < img src="..."> in the response. You won't be able to see the image in the tool you use to make the dialog and create intents but they will appear in your finished application.